# Design a circuit that takes a 3 bit binary and makes it (x^2 - x), using a decoder of your choice

Tags: circuit-design, decoder

[image][image]i tried making the circuit for each output on its own then make the final circuit
but i have a feeling that wrong
     any thoughts ?

Comment: Show us your work. You should probably have some truth tables. Explain why you don't think your solution is correct. We are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem with no work shown.

Comment: i posted the truth table

Comment: and i think that my solution is wrong because the question want me to use a decoder and i don't know if this is considered a decoder

Comment: Did it occur to to search "CMOS decoder"?  https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=CMOS+decoder&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, we must determine the sizes of the outputs and inputs.
If x is a 3-bit number, then x^2 is 6 bits, and x^2 - x the same.

---

Next we can make the truth table for a 3 bit input number and 6 bit output number:

- Input: 0 (dec) = 000 (bin), Output: 00 (dec) = 000000 (bin)
- Input: 1 (dec) = 001 (bin), Output: 00 (dec) = 000000 (bin)
- Input: 2 (dec) = 010 (bin), Output: 02 (dec) = 000010 (bin)
- Input: 3 (dec) = 011 (bin), Output: 06 (dec) = 000110 (bin)
- Input: 4 (dec) = 100 (bin), Output: 12 (dec) = 001100 (bin)
- Input: 5 (dec) = 101 (bin), Output: 20 (dec) = 011000 (bin)
- Input: 6 (dec) = 110 (bin), Output: 30 (dec) = 011110 (bin)
- Input: 7 (dec) = 111 (bin), Output: 42 (dec) = 101010 (bin)

Now that we know what output should be produced for a given input, we can derive logic functions for each of the 6 output bits using a Karnaugh map or otherwise. Each output bit depends only on 3 input bits, so the Karnaugh maps will be easy to do if you choose that approach. I will do some of them.

---

Clearly bit 0 of the output is always 0, so its function is trivial:

- Output[0] = 0

Let's do bit 1 now of the output now. We see that Output[1] is 1 only when the input is equal to 2, 3, 6, or 7. Thus we can write:

- Output[1] = (Input == 010) | (Input == 011) | (Input == 110) | (Input
  == 111)
- Simplifying, Output[1] = Input[1]

Moving on to the next bit, Output[2] is 1 only when the input is equal to 3, 4, or 6. So we have:

- Output[2] = (Input == 011) | (Input == 100) | (Input == 110)

Hopefully this is instructive regarding how to do this type of problem.
I will leave the other bits and drawing the gate-level circuit to you.